# PHP multiple post request

Tags: php, email, curl, post

UPDATE: Setup tested - it works - but my web-host cannot handle 600 email in about 6 seconds - I had each connection wait 20 seconds and then send one mail - those all went through

I have a mailing list with 600+ emails
I have a function to send out the 600+ emails

Unfortunately, there is a limit as to the execution time (90 seconds) - and therefore the script is shut down before it is completed. I cannot change the time with `set_time_limit(0)`, as it is set by my web-host (not in an ini file that i can change either)

My solution is to make post requests from a main file to a sub file that will send out chunks of 100 mails at a time. But will these be sent without delay - or will they wait for an answer before sending the next request?

The code:

```
for($i=0;$i<$mails;$i+100) {
    $url = 'http://www.bedsteforaeldreforasyl.dk/siteadmin/php/sender.php';
    $myvars = 'start=' . $i . '&emne=' . $emne . '&besked=' . $besked;

    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, 0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);

    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

`$mails` is the total number of recipients
`$start` is the start row number i the SQL statement

Will this (as I hope) start 6 parallel connections - or will it (as I fear) start 6 procesesses each after the other?

In the receiving script I have:

```
<br>
ignore_user_abort(true);<br>
$q1 = "SELECT * FROM maillist LIMIT $start,100 ORDER BY navn";
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure but it looks like it is going to start 6 procesesses

Comment: Will each wait for the other to complete - or will it be simultaneous?

Comment: I do not dare to answer that question I am not certain

Comment: i think curl_exec is blocking, so this will run in sequence. Maybe multi-exec will help http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

Comment: curl_exec is blocking, what i wonder is: even if you'd manage to send all mails in 1/6 of time with multi-exec, is this really the desidered behavior? 600+ mails sent in less than 90 seconds are a lot...

Comment: Why are you running this as curl at all? Is the script at another server, than your sender script? And can't you just send them from the server that runs this curl call? In that case, I'd just send them all as one mail, and set the 600 recipients as BCC.

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide some ideas on how the objective can be achieved.

1. First Option - Use `curl_multi_*` suite of functions. It provides non-blocking cURL requests.

   2 . Second Option - Use an asynchronous library like [amphp](https://amphp.org) or [ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org/). Though it would essentially provide the same benefit as `curl_multi_*`, IIRC.
2. Use [`pcntl_fork()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) to create separate processes and distribute the job as in worker nodes.
3. Use [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) extension, which essentially provides a userland PHP implementation of true multi-threading.

I'll warn you though, the last two options should be the last resort, since the parallel processing world comes up some spooky situations which can prove to be really pesky ;-).

I'd also probably suggest you that if you are planning to scale this sort of application, it'd be the best course of action to use some external service.

Comment: Multi-tasking in PHP does not have to be difficult.  PHP can pass the multi-tasking work off to the OS using stream_socket_client() as shown in my answer.

Comment: I never said it was difficult. All I said was that the land of parallel processing is queer with all the Mutexes and Locks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Create six php scripts, one for each 100 emails (or pass a value (e.g. 0-5) to a single script).
Create a main script to call these six sub-scripts.

Use `stream_socket_client()` to call the sub-scripts.
The six scripts will run simultaneously.
You can catch anything echoed back by the sub-scripts (e.g. status).

```
$timeout = 120;
$buffer_size = 8192;
$result = array();
$sockets = array();
$id = 0;    
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$urls[] = array('host' => 'www.example.com','path' => "http://www.example.com/mail1.php");
$urls[] = array('host' => 'www.example.com','path' => "http://www.example.com/mail2.php");
$urls[] = array('host' => 'www.example.com','path' => "http://www.example.com/mail3.php");
$urls[] = array('host' => 'www.example.com','path' => "http://www.example.com/mail4.php");
$urls[] = array('host' => 'www.example.com','path' => "http://www.example.com/mail5.php");
$urls[] = array('host' => 'www.example.com','path' => "http://www.example.com/mail6.php");
foreach($urls as $path){
  $host = $path['host'];
  $path = $path['path'];
  $http = "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $host\r\n\r\n";
  $stream = stream_socket_client("$host:80", $errno,$errstr, 120,STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT); 
  if ($stream) {
    $sockets[] = $stream;  // supports multiple sockets
    fwrite($stream, $http);
  }
  else { 
     $err .=  "$id Failed<br>\n";
  }
}
echo $err;

while (count($sockets)) {
  $read = $sockets; 
  stream_select($read, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, $timeout);
  if (count($read)) {
    foreach ($read as $r) { 
      $id = array_search($r, $sockets); 
      $data = fread($r, $buffer_size); 
      if (strlen($data) == 0) { 
     //   echo "$id Closed: " . date('h:i:s') . "\n\n\n";
        $closed[$id] = microtime(true);
        fclose($r); 
        unset($sockets[$id]);
      } 
      else {
        $result[$id] .= $data; 
      }
    }
  }
  else { 
 //   echo 'Timeout: ' . date('h:i:s') . "\n\n\n";
    break;
  }
}
var_export($result);
```